# What is the electrum bitcoin wallet password encryption method?

Tags: security, encryption, weaknesses

What method does Electrum bitcoin wallet use for password encryption?

I want to check to see if the file encrypted with the password is secure. And what are the ways around to decrypt it outside the electrum.

Answer (score 0):

https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-is-the-wallet-encrypted

> Electrum uses two separate levels of encryption:
>
> Your seed and private keys are encrypted using AES-256-CBC. The private keys are decrypted only briefly, when you need to sign a transaction; for this you need to enter your password. This is done in order to minimize the amount of time during which sensitive information is unencrypted in your computer’s memory.
>
> In addition, your wallet file may be encrypted on disk. Note that the wallet information will remain unencrypted in the memory of your computer for the duration of your session. If a wallet is encrypted, then its password will be required in order to open it. Note that the password will not be kept in memory; Electrum does not need it in order to save the wallet on disk, because it uses asymmetric encryption (ECIES).

see

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme
- https://electrum.org/#download

Comment: Having a password and file، Is there a way to decrypt the file outside of Electrum?

Comment: @Monero: as a software developer, my first thought is to inspect Electrum's Python source code, find where it reads and decrypts the file and cut & paste much of that into a separate program. Otherwise I don't know. Maybe there's some tool such as OpenSSL which supports the appropriate algorithm. You'd have to use a search engine to look for something like "ECIES decryption tool OR utility OR program". ... which finds things like https://pypi.org/project/eciespy/ (untested) - However the job may be not that simple.